# Time intervals query to return free time?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, phpmyadmin

I can see what I want to accomplish, but cannot figure out the right way to do it. I have a service beauty shop and want to get into my database my customers with the service they are having and the time interval range. For example:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ CustomerName ║                 INTERVAL                  ║ Nameservice ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 01 ║ John         ║ 18/01/2015 15:00 on 01/18/2015 16:00      ║ Manicure.   ║
║ 03 ║ Maria        ║ 18/01/2015 18:00 on 01/18/2015 19:00      ║ pedicure.   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Once I get my range I would like the query to return me the times that are free, for example from 16:00 to 18:00. I tried with PHPMyAdmin but there is no interval type datatype

Comment: do you need help with the query for the above database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relational database with two time fields: one for starting time of the procedure and the other for ending time.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `procedures` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `starting_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `ending_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `procedure_type` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: And now who to do is the query?